# Assigning variables from configuration file to int16_t variables in c++

Tags: c++, stringstream, istringstream

I have use stringstream to parse the configuration file. The c++ integer variables are working fine while assigning the values from the text file.However, when I assign the read value from configuration file to c++ int16_t variables, it just assigns a different value. I donot know what is going on.

This is my code:

```
void parseConfigurationFile(){
  //Variables
  int16_t int16_tValue;
  int firstIntegerValue;

  //File parsing code
  std::ifstream fin(configFileName);
  std::string line;
  std::istringstream sin;

  while (std::getline(fin, line)) 
  {
   sin.str(line.substr(line.find(":")+1));
   if (line.find("firstIntegerValue") != std::string::npos) {
       sin >> firstIntegerValue;
   }  
   else if (line.find("int16_tValue") != std::string::npos) {
       sin>>int16_tValue;
   }  
}
```

My configuration file looks like follows :

```
firstIntegerValue : 12
int16_tValue : 55555
```

What might be possibly going wrong here? I could not figure this out.

Comment: I suggest using `find` to find the ':' before making an `istringstream` instance.

Comment: Your `if-else` ladder is missing a final `else` clause.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, *watching* values in variables.  Debugging a program is often faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect your code or debug your code. Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session (indicate which statement is causing the issue, the expected behavior and the actual behavior).

Comment: Your code will continue if there is a file opening error.  You may want to fix it or not test for errors.

Comment: Also, I recommend placing the result of `find` into a temporary variable rather than in the `if` statement.  A temporary variable will be easier to use with the debugger.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is working fine for the firstIntegerValue.  It only doesnot work for int16_t value. It just places some random value for this one.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews removed the code that checks if the file is opened or not to  focus on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input, 55555, is beyond the range of `int16_t`. Since `int16_t` is a signed quantity, there is one bit reserved for the sign, so you have less positive range.  You are overflowing a signed 16-bit integer.

Your value may be interpreted as a negative number.

You may want to enter a smaller value or use `uint16_t`.